# How to redirect HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported to another page

Tags: spring, jsp, redirect, spring-mvc, annotations

I am building an application and I want to do a validation in which when user tries to access a POST method he should be redirected to a new Page. For example when I Login, the username and password validations are done in the post method that has

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/firstPage.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

So what I want to do is if user saves this link xyz.../firstPage.htm after the application is closed by pasting it in browser url, he should not get 405 error instead he should be redirected to another page that says You are not Authenticated to view this page.

How do I do this?

Regards,

Zingo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another method in your controller that handles the same URI, but with RequestMethod Get. It can simply shows a page with a login form asking the user to login.

This will also lead to a more standardized approach. Where a GET request to a URL shows the form, while POSTing credentials to the same URL logs you in.

Hope this helps.